# Is this a valid solution to Putnam 2017 A3

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, contest-math

**Problem:** Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers with $a<b$, and let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $(0, \infty)$
such that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$ but $f \neq g$. For every positive integer $n$, define
$$I_n = \int_a^b \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{(g(x))^n}\,dx$$
Show that $I_1, I_2, I_3, \dots$ is an increasing sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = \infty$.

Solutions are found [here](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2017s.pdf).

I had an idea for a solution, and I think it is somewhat similar to the third one provided, but I wanted to receive assurance from other people on whether this idea is valid. **Nevermind, I differentiated wrong. I'd like to see if there is a way to follow from this idea.**

First define the function
$$I(n)=\int_a^b \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{(g(x))^n}\, dx$$
where $n$ is a real number in the interval $[0,\infty)$. This is fine as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both positive. Moreover, for all positive integers, $I(n)=I_n$.

Taking the derivative wrt $n$ gives
$$\frac{d}{dn} I(n)=\int_a^b \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{(g(x))^n}\cdot \left(\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))\right)dx$$
This doesn't even seem like it is necessarily positive, so I don't think this approach works then, unless someone else has any ideas.

Comment: The derivative w.r.t. $n$ doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: So you're saying the derivative of $t\rightarrow \big(f(x)\big)^t$ is $t\big(f(x)\big)^{t-1}$?

Comment: Also note that you don't make use of all assumptions on $f$ and $g$, which seems suspicious.

Comment: @StefanLafon Yeah, that's why I was unsure of it. The justification I thought was similar to the Feynman trick or maybe Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Oh no! You're right. I messed up my derivative. Dang! Yep, I'm not sure if there is anyway to salvage this solution, but I'd like to see if anyone can figure out a way to extend it.

Comment: Letting $n$ take all real values, your differentiation is correct. But there must be $x$ where $f(x)>g(x)$ and $x'$ where $f(x')<g(x')$ so some other idea ( I dk what) is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Long comment.

Partial answer. Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\infty.$

Lemma. If $a<b$ and $h:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\,\int_a^b|h(x)|^ndx\,)^{1/n}=\max \{|h(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}.$ Proof is for the reader.

Now with $h(x)=|h(x)|=f(x)/g(x)$ we have $1<M=\max \{|h(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}.$ And we have $0<m=\min \{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}.$

Let $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $n>n_0\implies (\,\int_a^b|h(x)|^ndx\,)^{1/n}>\frac {1+M}{2}.$  Then $$n>n_0\implies I_n=\int_a^b h(x)^nf(x)dx\ge \int_a^b h(x)^nmdx=$$ $$=m\int_a^b h(x)^ndx>m\left(\frac {1+M}{2}\right)^n$$ and this last value $\to \infty$ because $m>0$ and $\dfrac {1+M}{2}>1.$

Comment: It looks that you proved the 1st part that the sequence has limit infinity. But it was also asked to prove its an increasing sequence.

Comment: @NivMan. That is why I called it a comment.